# Arabic encoding issue Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù… php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, text, encoding, arabic

> I want to display arabic text but charactere Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù…Ù„Ùƒ display.
>
> For example the word المملكة العربية السعودية display on Ø§Ù„Ù…Ù…Ù„ÙƒØ© Ø§Ù„Ø¹Ø±Ø¨ÙŠØ© Ø§Ù„Ø³Ø¹ÙˆØ¯ÙŠØ©

I add on my page always encoded on UTF-8:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

> but that not changed.

text is from mysqli database to php ..
any sugestions .. ?
all php pages are utf8 and database is

```
tried MyISAM utf8_general_ci
tried InnoDB
tried latin1_general_ci
tried utf8mb4 as well didnt work
```

tried :

```
 mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
 mysqli_query($con,"SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
 mysqli_query($con,"SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_unicode_ci'");
```

all still same result..

> Have you a idea about that?

Comment: no still same , chaging to `utf8mb4` didnt solve it

Comment: Is it saving proper in db?

Comment: yes it is saving properly

Comment: solution : download a local copy of db , make a php page utf8 - unix - bom  , than open text from db from php page which will read as plain text locally i dont know why but it did ,, make new insert query than insert the new input text to online database as plain text.